# How do I create a custom role for entities in Sphinx?

Tags: python-sphinx

In my project we define threats/risks and countermeasures. I want to keep track and refer to both types of entities in Sphinx, as well as generating a list of both threats/risks and the countermeasures. Let's say I have 30 risks and 50 countermeasures (many-to-many relationship).

I'd be happy just to have a lists of both and the ability to refer to each other by numbers (e.g. "risk #23", "countermeasure #12"). It would be even better if the system could display the relationship automatically.

The content of both is let's say a single paragraph or even shorter, so that's why I dislike to use regular headings. And I cannot refer to items in lists or table rows. So, I'm looking for something like a `Figure` in Sphinx (numbered, with caption), but then for arbitrary types of entities.

My current approach is to create a custom RST role for this. Is this the right approach? If so, where to start?

Comment: Potentially related question: [Sphinx: how to add a role and directive alias - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34218728/sphinx-how-to-add-a-role-and-directive-alias)