# Sphinx: how to add a role and directive alias

Tags: python-sphinx

I frequently use the `:math:` role and `.. math::` directive, which is so frequent that I want to make a shorter alias `m` for them. How can I achieve it in Sphinx?

Comment: `:math:` is a role. `.. math::` is a directive. Is it the latter that you want to add an alias for? Or both?

Comment: @mzjn I prefer both, but either would be useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the following code snippet to conf.py. It defines a `m` directive and a `m` role that can be used as aliases of `math`:

```py
from sphinx.ext.mathbase import MathDirective, math_role

def setup(app):
    app.add_directive('m', MathDirective)
    app.add_role('m', math_role)
```

See also:

- http://sphinx-doc.org/extdev/tutorial.html#the-setup-function
- http://sphinx-doc.org/extdev/appapi.html